# Is making POST requests with additional parameters via link_to acceptable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

It's easy to make a link in Rails make a POST request. Something like `link_to 'Click me', some_path, :method => :post`. This works great... unless you need to pass additional parameters in. Because there's no way to make an actual POST request from a link, Rails fakes it with a GET request, so that means if you try to pass additional parameters to `some_path`, it builds it into the query string. So when you mouseover you get a link that looks like this:

`/some_path?foo=var&foo=bar[foo][bar]`

Normally this wouldn't be too bad, except it gets really ugly if you've got a controller that is expecting some nested params.

So my question is, does this bother anyone else, or is just me?

The only workaround I can think of is to change the href to a `#`, add a hidden form nearby, and add a click handler to the link that serializes the form and submits it when the link is clicked. That makes the link degrade ungracefully and is an awful lot of work for what basically amounts to an aesthetic gripe. But I'm pretty obsessive about my URLs. Is there an easier way? Or am I just being crazy and should just deal with the params in the query string?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a really, really good reason why you don't use a form?

Comment: Well, that's one option I'd considered, just making the link itself a form. Although it could be very difficult (or maybe even impossible) to style the form/submit button, depending on how it needs to look. But the real reason is it just seems like overkill. I'm leaning towards simplicity over style in this case.

Comment: It's not too difficult to make a button look like a link but you spend a fair bit of time between browsers adjusting padding etc. I actually don't understand what you're trying to achieve though. Why do you want it to be a post request?

Comment: The button/link needs to hit the the create action of a resource, which would be a POST request.

Comment: But it's not a post request, it's a get request and in my opinion you should make the create route a get request if that's what you need. I know it's defying restful crud convention but surely what you're trying to do is worse?

Answer (score 1):

The web is an ugly place, and one of the things that's annoying is you can't make a link POST without creating a form or doing some wild JavaScript to handle it in the background.

It bothers people who are concerned with how tidy their URLs are, which is a concern far too few actually have in all honesty, but the only reliable solution is a form plus a tidy little jQuery extension to handle the trigger.

To avoid seeing an ugly URL in the browser, though, you can always make the request via AJAX, send back a URL, then redirect to that URL once the AJAX part is completed. This gives you the opportunity to present a "Submitting" or "Requesting" type spinner.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's probably more effort than it's worth. I guess I just have to get used to sending some nasty looking URLs.

Comment: The URL might be ugly, but the experience doesn't have to be. Remember that your average users are not examining the Firebug net browser.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myOnClick() {
  // ... do custom ajax w/whatever parameters.
  alert("myOnClick()");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onClick="myOnClick();return false;">link text</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser will show the href value in the status bar, but the `myOnClick()` function is what is actually called when the link is clicked.  The `return false` part is required to prevent the browser from processing the `href` attribute.

The `myOnClick()` function can the perform whatever operation, like an ajax request, with whatever parameters you want.